# Text to columns by fixed width in R

Tags: r

I have a large data frame in which I'm trying to separate the values from one column into two. The values are character then text such as AU2847 or AU1824. I want the first column to be AU and the second to be the corresponding 4 digit number.

I am also restricted to the base r packages so I believe strsplit will be our best bet- but can't figure out how to make it split after 2nd character and create 2 columns from it.

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) on making an R question that folks can help with. That includes a sample of data and all necessary code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I regularly use these two functions:

```
substrRight <- function(x, n){
  substr(x, nchar(x)-n+1, nchar(x))
}
```

and

```
substrLeft <- function(x, n){
  substr(x, 1,n)
}
```

Which cutoff n characters left or right of the string

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
as.data.frame(
  do.call(rbind,
          strsplit(sub("^(.+?)(\\d+)", "\\1_\\2", df$col),
                   split="_")
          )
  )
```

Whereby `df` is the name of your data frame and `col` the name of your column.

This then inserts artificially an underscore between the text and first number - this way you can use underscore as an argument to `strsplit`.

Answer (score 0):

There are several options to do this. You can subset by position using `substr()`, or you can use `gsub()` and call be reference too. Subsetting by position will be faster but inflexible (you would have to have a huge dataframe to notice a difference in time), and using regex (`gsub()` will be a little slower but is much more flexible). E.g.:

```
df[c("col2", "col3", "col2b", "col3b")] <- list(substr(df$col1, 1, 2),
                                                substr(df$col1, 3, 6),
                                                gsub("([[:alpha:]]+)(\\d+)", "\\1", df$col1),
                                                gsub("([[:alpha:]]+)(\\d+)", "\\2", df$col1))

df
    col1 col2 col3 col2b col3b
1 AU2847   AU 2847    AU  2847
2 AU1824   AU 1824    AU  1824
```

**Data**:

```
df <- data.frame(col1 = c("AU2847", "AU1824"), stringsAsFactors = F)
```

Answer (score 0):

We can use `strsplit()` together with a *regular expression* which uses a *lookbehind* assertion:

```
x  <- c("AU2847", "AU1824")
strsplit(x, "(?<=[A-Z]{2})", perl = TRUE)
```

> ```
> [[1]]
> [1] "AU"   "2847"
>
> [[2]]
> [1] "AU"   "1824"
> ```

The *lookbehind regular expression* tells `strsplit()` to split each string after two capital letters. There is no need to artificially introduce a character to split on as in [arg0naut91's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/60042066/3817004).

---

Now, the OP has mentioned that the character vector to be splitted is a column of a larger data.frame. This requires some additional code to append the list output of `strsplit()` as new columns to the data.frame:

Let's assume we have this data.frame

```
DF <- data.frame(x, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Now, the new columns can be appended by:

```
DF[, c("col1", "col2")] <- do.call(rbind, strsplit(DF$x, "(?<=[A-Z]{2})", perl = TRUE))
DF
```

> ```
>        x col1 col2
> 1 AU2847   AU 2847
> 2 AU1824   AU 1824
> ```